# Can an audio receiver with a 130v-rated switching power supply be modified to be used without a power transformer?

Tags: voltage, amplifier, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, power-engineering

I have a Harman Kardon AVR, imported from the US, which uses an SMPS (130v) that I will use in Asia. Is there a way to modify the component inside the Power supply so that I can use it without a bulky, and rather unstable transformer? I know the simpler way is to just use one, but humour me if you have any wild suggestion.

[image][image]

Comment: Ask the manufacture.

Answer (score 1):

If it hasn't been designed for 110 - 240 V supply then you are out of luck.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr5quj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All the switched mode power supplies rectify the mains to provide a high voltage DC supply that is fed to a transformer whose negative terminal is chopped by the switcher transistor. The capacitor(s) will charge up to √2 * Vin. If it's a 120 V supply that will be about 200 V. Check your capacitors and you'll probably find that's all they're rated for.

For 220 - 240 V operation you would need 400 V capacitors (and rectifiers, transistors, surge suppressors, insulation - have I put you off trying yet?).

Comment: A Vrms of 120V equates to a Vpeak of ~170V not 200V. Similarly, for Vrms of 240V it's a Vpeak of 340V.

Comment: Your maths is correct. I've usually seen 200 V and 400 V caps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are very lucky the 117VAC input rectifier circuit will be a full wave voltage doubler that will make about 350 VDC to run the SMPS.  You could carefully probe around with the DVM with the Amp running on 117VAC, if you see say 350 then you could do a fullwave bridge to run 230VAC.  Double check the ratings of fuses and EMC caps. I would install a fuse of half the current rating because the expected current draw will be half because the voltage is doubled.

This voltage doubling concept is used sometimes to reduce the number of component changes when going from 230 to 117.  A penalty of this approach is larger caps on the DC bus for a given power output. This approach is more likely to be seen on forward and half bridge converters.  Flybacks tend to be lower power and are easier to design for 90 to 270VAC.